# Invalid file reference, where am i going wrong?

Tags: java, image, nullpointerexception, embedded-resource, imageicon

Whenever i try to draw an image with paintComponent and ImageIcon i get a NullPointerException from an unknown source, then pointing to my image getter and the thread start.

Image getter

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("C:/Users/Rhys/Desktop/workspace/Mindcracker RPG/Res/Background.jpg"));
```

Thanks for any answers

Comment: Is the file path valid?

Comment: Yes it is, i tried using the / and the \\ aswell between each path

Comment: Well, you should have seen enough Q&As to realize we need to know a) The root of the class-path b) that a path prefixed with a drive letter won't find anything using that method.

Comment: So what should my path be ?? Referenced from the internet or a File e.g. File file = new File();

Comment: Are you sure you need to use this.getClass().getResource("FileName") instead of new ImageIcon("FileName")...?

Comment: Yeah, i tried what you said before, ill try again

Just a blank screen :(

Comment: Use the JavaDoc it is your friend and explains exactly how to do what you want!

Comment: For tips see the [embedded-resource info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).  One major tip.  Always prefix the path with `/` (the root of the class-path) to account for resource access from code in packages.  Keep using `getResource(..)` for an URL rather than `String` for a `File`.  That is an (at best) temporary solution.  Tip:  Add @SameerSawla (or whoever - the `@` is important) to notify someone of a new comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use the JavaDoc:

`this.getClass().getResource()` only for acquiring resources on the `ClassPath` where `/` represents the `default package`.

You are supplying a fully qualified path which won't work.

What you need to do is use this [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.lang.String%29):

```
public ImageIcon(String filename)
```

> Creates an ImageIcon from the specified file.
>
> The specified String can be a file name or a file path. When
>   specifying a path, use the Internet-standard forward-slash ("/") as a
>   separator. (The string is converted to an URL, so the forward-slash
>   works on all systems.)

For example, specify:

```
new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Rhys/Desktop/workspace/Mindcracker RPG/Res/Background.jpg");
```

*note that there is a space in the path there and this path eventually gets converted into a `file:://` URL so you might want to take that into consideration*